# How to refactor snap.svg code

Tags: snap.svg

I'm sure this code could be simpler possibly with a for loop.

```
var paper = Snap('#frame');
frame = paper.polygon(1 ,0 , 1, 1 , 0 ,1 , 0 ,0);
frame.attr({
  fill: 'yellow',
});

trFunc = function(){
    frame.animate({points:"0.9,0.175 , 1, 1 , 0 ,1 , 0 ,0"},700,mina.elastic);
}
brFunc = function(){
    frame.animate({points:"0.9,0.175 , 0.9, 0.825 , 0 ,1 , 0 ,0"},700,mina.elastic);
}

blFunc = function(){
  frame.animate({
    points:"0.9,0.175,0.9,0.825,0.1,0.825,0,0"
  },700,mina.elastic) 
}

tlFunc = function(){
  frame.animate({
    points:"0.9,0.175,0.9,0.825,0.1,0.825,0.1,0.175"
  },700,mina.elastic)
}

setTimeout(trFunc, 200);
setTimeout(brFunc, 400);
setTimeout(blFunc, 600);
setTimeout(tlFunc, 800);
```

Comment: Questions amount *working* code for which the motive is improvement, rather than bug fixing, may be better on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Also, out of interest (I don't know about snap.svg), why are your last two functions formatted differently to the first two?

Comment: If you were doing a lot of stuff in sequences, I did write a small func to make it easier that may be of use http://svg.dabbles.info/snaptut-animateframe (most of the code is just the example, the main func lower down is pretty much all thats needed)

Comment: Thanks for your comments Wai. The formatting inconsistencies are purely my bad. I need to keep an eye on it. I was not aware of Code Review so I'll use that next time.

Comment: Hi Ian thanks for your time. Id love to write a function for this. Might you be able to help me through it?